# Can a "brain-sensing headband" be used to train to be less stressed?

Tags: consumer-products, neurology

Interaxon claim that their "brain-sensing headband", [Muse](http://www.choosemuse.com), together with an iOS or Android app, can provide a user with some feedback that can be used to train the brain to become more calm and less stressed.

> A brain fitness tool that helps you do more with your mind, and more with your life, by helping you learn to manage stress, stay calm, and stay focused.
>
> Improve your physical, emotional, and cognitive health. See and feel improvements in your mental state in areas such as focus, composure, productivity, motivation, and emotional intelligence.

Can such a "brain-sensing" consumer product be used to manage stress and be thus beneficial for an individual's health?

Comment: Hmmm... I see this as a tricky one. In my head, it breaks down as: Can Electroencephalography (EEG) feedback make meditation more effective? Does this device do a sufficient task of EEG? Even if both of those are false, does selling a placebo encourage gadget-loving stressed people to give meditation a try? [This isn't the only possible way to tackle it, and it assumes meditation is effective, that would need referencing too.]

Comment: @Oddthinking - ISTR that efficacy of meditation was covered on Skeptics before.

Comment: @Oddthinking Maybe the question should be rephrased to ask whether such a headband is better than a placebo. Anyway, [this article](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-myths/201302/read-paying-100s-neurofeedback-therapy-0) is somewhat relevant. It points to a few references that show that, at least for ADHD treatment, real neurofeedback is no better than placebo neurofeedback.